# Cant play videos faster than 2x with youtube iframe api

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-iframe-api

Youtube iframe API doesn't allow player.setPlaybackRate() to be set higher than 2 is there any other way to speed it up more than 2x?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try this script https://greasyfork.org/it/scripts/421610-youtube-speed-up/code

It overwrites `_yt_player.xx.yy.zz.kk.getAvailablePlaybackRates()` to return an array [0.25 ... 4].

Answer (score 0):

The supported playback speeds are listed by `player.getAvailablePlaybackRates()` on the Youtube iframe API.

Youtube itself defines what playback speeds it supports. You'll want to implement your own video player (i.e. download the video from YouTube server-side and serve it to your client via a different video player) if you want to change this further.

Comment: Well that is something i wanted to avoid since it will be quite slow

Comment: Then, in answer to your question "is there any other way to speed it up more than 2x?", the answer is no.